# Static format validators in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-1.8.7

In an `ActiveRecord` model, are there any static/canned formats I can use? For instance, when validating the format of an email address I can either make a static regex to reuse on other models or perhaps use some static that already exists in the framework.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  EMAIL_FORMAT = /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, ..., :email

  validates :email, :format => EMAIL_FORMAT
end
```

I figured I'd be able to simply do:

```
validates :email, :format => ActiveRecord::SOME_STATIC_EMAIL_FORMAT
```

or:

```
validates :email, :format => :email
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [doc](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format):

```
validates :email, format: { with: EMAIL_FORMAT }
```

Comment: I don't think that helps - I was looking for some static regex/formats in ActiveRecord I could reuse without writing new regex/formats of my own. I expected there to be a set of common formats included in the framework. The code as I have it works fine so it's no an issue of something not working, just don't want to duplicate work.

Comment: I always use `Devise.email_regexp`